# Simple trigonometry identity

Tags: trigonometry

It has been more than sixty years since I studied
trigonometry, and I cannot come up with a fundamental proof that the product of cos(20), cos(40) and cos(80) is exactly 0.125.
(Arguments in degrees, of course.)  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{split}
\cos(20)\cos(40)\cos(80) &= \frac{\sin(20)\cos(20)\cos(40)\cos(80)}{\sin(20)} \\
&= \frac{0.5\sin(40)\cos(40)\cos(80)}{\sin(20)} \\
&= \frac{0.25\sin(80)\cos(80)}{\sin(20)} \\
&= \frac{0.125\sin(160)}{\sin(20)} \\
&= \frac{0.125\sin(20)}{\sin(20)} \\
&= 0.125 \\
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thanks so much.  Perhaps I would have had more insight into this

Comment: Thanks.  Perhaps I would have had more insight into this one if the product had been shown as cos(A)cos(2A)cos(4A)